# Which Graph Database (Orient or Titan) is good to use with spring and liferay?

Tags: spring, liferay-6, graph-databases, orientdb, titan

please help me , I'm quite confuse while deciding to use graph database , I'm developing a Social networking website . so please suggest me which I have to use .

I developing this project using spring and liferay 6.2.

Please help me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing anything about your requirements (question is too broad). I can only say, for a typical social **networking** site a Graph database is a perfect fit (best fit in most cases). Using a java based stack OrientDB, Tinkerpop and Neo4J are all excellent candidates.

Answer (score 10):

Titan as product is dead about 2 weeks ago. DataStax (Cassandra company) hired the Titan team, but not the product. They preferred to abandon Titan. Here the official announcement:

http://www.zdnet.com/article/datastax-snaps-up-aurelius-and-its-titan-team-to-build-new-graph-database/

> "We're not going to do an integration. The play here is we'll take
>   everything that's been done on Titan as inspiration, and maybe some of
>   the Titan project will make it into DSE Graph," DataStax engineering
>   VP Martin Van Ryswyk said... But we're really going to build something
>   new because we're going to be able now to take advantage of Cassandra
>   specifically and DSE features specifically. It will be an engineering
>   effort to build a new product. We will not be supporting or
>   integrating Titan as a product into our portfolio."

And this is the official announcement in Titan group:

> "However, there is also some sadness in this announcement. As we
>   transition to DataStax, we will find little time to contribute toTitan
>   and interact with the Titan community. We will miss that and hope that
>   it will be carried forward."

Now, some users was very pissed off about this news. Read this:

> "Not even that. They pulled the plug without a stable product, no
>   prior notice and not caring about the companies that used a buggy
>   system that broke compatibility every time just because a version 1.0
>   was promised."

(source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/WtU6om8CtqI/Q1_AIFRA4mkJ)

So after few days of flame in the group, Titan team said "Ok, Titan is alive", but this has been the reaction on Hacker News:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9025798

I'm not talking about Titan vs OrientDB from technical perspective (I'm the OrientDB author, so it would be unbiased), but I'm just pointing here that creating a new project based on a dead product seems a not so good idea. So you can go with OrientDB or wait for the new Cassandra DSE (Commercial only?) with graph features "inspired" to Titan.

Comment: Thanks you so much for such a brief intro of titan . now I decided to use orient  only . Thanks #Luca

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) and see for yourself which database works best for you. It is a Tinkerpop blueprints Spring-Data abstraction allowing you to switch to potentially any graph database that implements the blueprints API - which both OrientDB and TitanDB do, and the project already includes those databases.

**Note:** [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) is a work in progress and may not yet fit all your requirements, but we'll get there.

Answer (score -2):

Neo4J has native spring-data support.
http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/

You can also use Blueprints (https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki), which allows you to switch backend database easily.

Comment: Agree with this. Neo4J seems to be the one to go for with Spring.

Comment: @Alexander although your opinion is valuable, it does not seem to answer OP's question "_..Orient or Titan..?_"

Comment: I can use Neo4j , infect it was our first choice but it is not purely open source . and we are just start-up. so that's why I decided to use either orient DB or titan.    any way thanks for  answering .